# Is $\forall x (\phi)$ a formula in ZF even if $\phi$ does not contain x?

Tags: logic, axioms

I was reading *A Quick Introduction To Basic Set Theory* by Anush Tserunyan, and in definition 1.1, the author defined a notation of a formula in ZF with few criterias. One of them states:

> If $\phi$ is a formula and $x$ is a variable, then $\forall x(\phi)$ and $\exists x(\phi)$ are formulas.

I remember in first-order logic, the formula is defined similarly, but it requires $\phi$ to contain the restricting variable, namely, x, in the above. Is it different in the case of ZF and can we write something like $\forall x(y=y)$?

Also, the author also said that $\phi(x)$ emphasized that this formula "says something about a set (variable) x". Should I assume this implies $\phi(x)$ **must** contains x? (for instance, in the case of axiom schema 5 of Comprehension.)

Comment: If $\phi$ does not use $x$ as a variable, $\forall x(\phi)$ and $\exists x(\phi)$ are equivalent to $\phi.$ But it is certainly still allowed.

Comment: In natural language we make certain assumptions about _relevance_. Saying "Suppose x is a number. Then 5 is prime" sounds weird in natural language because we're searching for a connection between the two sentences. (This is one of _Grice's maxims_.) But in formal logic we don't have any such restriction, so $\forall x\in\Bbb N,{\rm prime}(5)$ is fine. (Grice's maxims come from the _cooperative principle_, the assumption that in most communication, the speaker and listener are cooperating. Formal logic is not cooperative in this way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're mistaken about first-order logic - there is no such requirement. $\forall x\,(y=y)$ is a perfectly good formula of first-order logic (and of ZF set theory).

When we write $\varphi(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, we mean that the only variables occurring free in $\varphi$ are among the $n$ variables $x_1,\dots,x_n$. There is no requirement that all $n$ of these variables actually appear free in $\varphi$. For example, $\varphi(x)$ might be $\exists y\,(y=y)$. We can interpret this formula as saying something about $x$, just not something interesing!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Maybe I used a weird textbook to learn first-order logic, which explicitly stated that the variable must be contained in $\phi$. Although I agree with you now, would you mind giving an example of a case where the presence of the restricted variable in the formula is required to make a statement valid? It is quite interesting when I look at the axiom of replacement and something like the definition of a function again, if $\phi$ does not contain the restricted variables, these statements/definitions do not make much sense to me.

Comment: What textbook did you use? Here are some examples for you: $\{x\in A\mid \forall y\, (y=y)\}$ and $\{x\in A\mid \exists y\, (y\neq y)\}$ are both valid applications of the axiom schema of comprehension. The first is $A$ and the second is $\varnothing$. The constant function $F(x)=\varnothing$ is definable by the formula $\varphi(x,y): \forall z\,(z\notin y)$, in which $x$ does not appear free. Applying the axiom of replacement to this function gives $F[A]=\{\varnothing\}$ when $A$ is non-empty.

Comment: @wsz_fantasy The restriction that the variable $x$ must be contained in $\phi$ is meaningless anyway since such a restriction can always be circumvented by changing $\phi$ to $\phi \lor (P(x) \land \lnot P(x))$, where $P(x)$ is an arbitrary formula containing $x$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  Thank you for the examples. I learned about some basics of logic a long time ago using a textbook used by Tsinghua University, written in Chinese. It is very interesting that what I described previously is the definition they used when introducing what is a formula in predicate logic. In the chapter where it formally introduced the model of first-order logic, the definition is different and matched what you have said.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go over how formula are constructed in ZFC.

Atomic Formula are formula of the form:

$x_i$∈$x_j$; $x_i$=$x_j$

where i,j are natural numbers.

If $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are Formula, then

$\phi$ ∧ $\varphi$

$\neg \phi$

(∃$x_i)\phi$

are all formula.

These are sufficient, since we can build disjunction,universal quantification, and implication by just applying these.

Notice that:

If $\phi$ is the formula $x_2$=$x_2$

then:

(∃$x_4)(x_2=x_2$)

is a formula.

Definition: Let ψ be a quantifier

then (ψ$x_j$)$\phi$ is a formula, we say that   (ψ$x_j$)$\phi$ is in the scope of (ψ$x_j$)

An instance of a variable is bound if lies in the scope of a quantifier acting on that same variable. i.e. if the variable that the quantifier is acting on occurs in the scope, it is an instance of a bound variable.

An instance of a variable is free if it is not bounded.

So, In (∃$x_4)(x_2=x_2$)

$x_4$ is bounded, and $x_2$ is free

Notice that the formula doesn't say anything about $x_4$. If instead it was $x_5$ the formula would be the same.

Formula say things about their free variables. They express properties about their free variables.

So, here we would say $\phi(x_2)$ to emphasize that $x_2$ is a free variable i.e. it is not bounded. However, $x_2$ need not appear anywhere in the formula, and there may be other variables which are free, that are just not being given emphasis.

Bounded variables are merely "dummy variables", whether it's $x_4$ or $x_5$ doesn't actually change anything in terms of the truth value of $\phi$

Another Example:

$x_2$ = $x_4$ ∧ (∃$x_4)(x_2∈x_4)$

All instances of $x_2$ are free, so $x_2$ is free.

The first instance of $x_4$ is free,

but the second instance of $x_4$ is bounded, as is the third instance.

As bounded variables are "dummy". Their choice is arbitrary.

So,

(∃$x_2)\phi(x_1)$

(∃$x_3)\phi(x_1)$

are equivalent